# MapReduce specific Collection using MongoDB & Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In Mongoose, using Find I am able to do something like bellow.

```
var activeUserQuests = ['51a02dade4b02780aeee5ab7', '51a0a40ce4b0cbb4519a8f69'];
 Quest.find({_id: { $in: activeUserQuests} }, function(err, doc){
     callback(doc);
 });
```

What I'd like to do, is to do something similar, however go through a MapReduce function.  Currently I have the following.

```
var o = {};
o.map = function() {
    emit(this.problem.id, {problem:this.problem.title,quest: 
        {
            title:this.title,
            created_date: this.created_date,
            updated_date: this.updated_date,
            author: this.author,
            description: this.description
        }
    });
}
o.reduce = function(previous, current) {
    var array = [];
    var res = {quests:array};
    current.forEach(function (v) {
        res.quests.push(v);
    });
    return res;
}
```

And calling the method like this

```
    findAll: function(callback){
        Quest.mapReduce(o, function(error, model, stats) {
            callback(model);
        });
     }
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "51a02dade4b02780aeee5ab7",
    "title": "Foo",
    "created_date": 2342423423423,
    "updated_date": 23424234234233
  },
   ///This one should not show up...
  {
    "_id": "99s8d7f9sdf79d9f7ds8f7",
    "title": "Bar",
    "created_date": 2342423423423,
    "updated_date": 23424234234233
  },
  {
    "_id": "51a0a40ce4b0cbb4519a8f69",
    "title": "Bazz",
    "author": "sdfsdfsf",
    "created_date": 2342423423423,
    "updated_date": 2342423423423,
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  }
]
```

This works great, however I'd like to only show items that are fed through an array, as I did with the find().  Essentially, all I want to do is...based on an arbitrary number of items and producers, only show and group my own.  I am assuming that by providing a list of IDs, I might speed up the return, in the event that there are a lot of items.

Comment: Your mapreduce format is incorrect, you actually need to return exactly the same format from reduce as you emit as second argument (value)

Comment: And I'm guessing what you are looking for is to pass {query:{}} to mapReduce, though I'm not sure why you want to do this with mapReduce

Comment: My reasoning is that I need the return to be grouped in a specific manner, however I only want one users data to be there at a time.  Currently everything gets returned in the correct format.  I will look into {query:{}}, but if you have any other leads that would be great too. Still trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i was looking for was

```
o.query = {_id: { $in: activeUserQuests} }
```

similar code block

```
 findTimelineByQuery: function (query, fields, options, callback) {

        var obj = {};

        obj.map = function() {
            emit(Date.UTC(this.created.getFullYear(), this.created.getMonth(), this.created.getDate()), {
                created:this.created,
                title:this.title,
                type: this.type,
                id: this._id,
                owner: this.owner,
                value: this.value
            });
        };

        obj.reduce = function(previous, current) {
            var array = [];
            var res = {items:array};

            current.forEach(function (v) {
                res.items.push(v);
            });
            return res;
        };

        obj.verbose = true;
        obj.query = query;

        _Items.mapReduce(obj, function(error, model, stats) {
            callback(model);
        });


    },
```

I missed the "Other options:" section here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce